# Difference between May, Could, Can or Might?

Tags: word-choice, difference, modal-verbs

My teacher's sent an assignment and asked the difference among these modals. However, the more I do research,the more the sites say there's no difference. And previously I'd seen that *may* expresses **higher** possibly than *might*, so that's why I'm confused. And I'd also never seen *could* and *can* being used for possibly.

Could you help me?

Comment: You have just used one of them yourself! _Could you help me_ is a polite way of asking for assistance. _Can you help me_ asks less politely, but perhaps with more urgency, if it is possible for someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

### Can and could

When used for or with "possibly" it's representing that such an action is possible and it's outside of your control, if circumstances are correct. "It could rain today." "The blade can hurt you." You don't say "I could do it" when you aren't sure about if you could actually do it. (If you say that, it's kind of a dismissal that you don't want to do it.)

### May and might

These are used for your own uncertainty over an action. "I might be able to make it." or "I may be able to do "

Comment: Also, _may_ refers more to a present uncertainty. "I may be able to come if I'm free." "I might have been able to come if I hadn't sprained my ankle the day before."